# How to add multiple values into one variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables, postman

I got an array :

```
"operators": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "name": "Player"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "Facilator"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Coordinator"
        }
    ],
```

**I want to set new variable to contain value of keys "id" only** .
I'm using this script:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

pm.collectionVariables.set("operators_id",jsonData.operators[0].id);
```

This will return new variable **"operators_id" = 4**

**I need the variable "operators_id" = 4,3,2** . Could you please show me how? Thanks in advance

Comment: after parsing the json structure: `jsonData.operators.map(x => x.id).join()`

Comment: Thanks you so much. It's working now , appreciate it ! :)

Comment: Sorry for this inconvenience, and how about to get "operators_id" = 4,3 only?
I tried with this script but not working :(

var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody); pm.collectionVariables.set("operators_id",jsonData.operators[0,1].id);

Comment: you need to manipulate the array. you can slice the array or better use filter before using map. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: Thanks you so much. Now I'm using splice() to cut the array then using map to get the value I want